# Joomla install stuck on tables creation

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

If you have problem (infinite loop) when installing Joomla using the web installer, face an issue while creating tables or copying data, this post can help you (i hope).

As Lodder said, in fact it's not a real infinite loop but just a timeout of the server (when executing the code).

Comment: The question post is meant to describe the problem!! There's nothing in your question (besides the title) that would do it.

Comment: My installation script also failed on tables creation. It was because I was using MySQL 5.0.x instead of required 5.1.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your php.ini and put it :

```
max_execution_time = 3000
memory_limit = 128M
```

And restart the service!

Comment: these values are changed when the server is timing out, not on an infinite loop ;) Might be best to enhance your question little

Comment: just drop down max_execution_time afterwards; it can be dangerous leaving that on a production site

Comment: right Dagon, just edit the values to do the import and next, put the default value.

Answer (score 0):

This may due to the false information provided in database configuration. Check your Username and Password to the database.

If you did not change the user name and password in server installation then leave

**Username** as **root** and **Password** as empty text field.

Hope this will work for you....

Comment: If the database username and password were wrong, then an error would appear on that specific page and the user would not be allowed to progress to the next step

Answer (score 0):

set your php.ini with this value and try

```
upload_max_filesize = 600M
post_max_size = 550M
max_execution_time = 5000
```